# query to compare sales of product in two years

Tags: sql

I am new to sql. can u guys please help me out with this query

table name : `sales`

```
product_id   sales    year
1            2000    2007
2            3000    2007
1            4000    2008
```

I want to compare the sales of my product with product id=1 in year 2007 and 2008 and get the result in query
so, output should be like

```
 product_id    sales in 2007  sales in 2008   
1                  2000           3000
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of query result you want is better done via client-side display-time manipulations. You can trivially get your data with:

```
SELECT year, SUM(sales)
FROM sales
WHERE product_id = 1
GROUP BY year
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I totally agree with @MarcB, if you still want to do it your way you should run this query:

```
select product_id,
  sum(if(year = 2007, sales, 0)) `sales in 2007`,
  sum(if(year = 2008, sales, 0)) `sales in 2008`
from products
where product_id = 1
group by product_id
```

Note `sales in 2008` are not `3000` as you showed in your example but rather `4000`!

Comment: What database supports if() like that? I've always seen CASE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,YEAR,SALES,
LEAD(SALES,1) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY SALES) AS FOLLOWING_YEAR_SALES
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

You can use the above query to get a new column with the following year sales. for the difference between two-year sales is easy to calculate.